# Compilation of Tesseract 3.02 on debug mode x64 errors

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2017, tesseract

I went through Tesseract wiki in order to install **Tesseract 3.05.1** from [source code](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/releases/tag/3.05.01), but I faced a problem when [compiling with cppan](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling) (when I launch it, it stops) and tried the [unofficael installer](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki) but didn't find the libraries I have to include from their builded Tesseract. So, I d't know what to do in order to have a version of Tesseract that works with my windows 64bit on visual studio 2017.

Note:I already generated opencv build using cmake for visual studio 15 2017 64bit.
=> I want my project to work on x64, not win32(x68).

I have tesseract 3.02 but compiling it in a project, caused errors.(conflicts between x86 and x64) and ***I don't prefer to use Tesseract 3.02*** because it's an old version.

The errors I get when trying to test with Tesseract 3.02 are in the following code:

```
#include <baseapi.h>
#include <allheaders.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI api;
    api.Init("", "eng", tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT);
    api.SetPageSegMode(static_cast<tesseract::PageSegMode>(7));
    api.SetOutputName("out");

    cout << "File name : ";
    char image[256];
    cin >> image;
    PIX   *pixs = pixRead(image);

    STRING text_out;
    api.ProcessPages(image, NULL, 0, &text_out);

    cout << text_out.string();

}
```

Errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: RedEyeRemover, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>redEyeRemover.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl STRING::STRING(void)" (??0STRING@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
1>redEyeRemover.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl STRING::~STRING(void)" (??1STRING@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
1>redEyeRemover.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: char const * __cdecl STRING::string(void)const " (?string@STRING@@QEBAPEBDXZ) referenced in function main
1>redEyeRemover.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl tesseract::TessBaseAPI::TessBaseAPI(void)" (??0TessBaseAPI@tesseract@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
1>redEyeRemover.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl tesseract::TessBaseAPI::~TessBaseAPI(void)" (??1TessBaseAPI@tesseract@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
1>redEyeRemover.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl tesseract::TessBaseAPI::SetOutputName(char const *)" (?SetOutputName@TessBaseAPI@tesseract@@QEAAXPEBD@Z) referenced in function main
1>redEyeRemover.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init(char const *,char const *,enum tesseract::OcrEngineMode,char * *,int,class GenericVector<class STRING> const *,class GenericVector<class STRING> const *,bool)" (?Init@TessBaseAPI@tesseract@@QEAAHPEBD0W4OcrEngineMode@2@PEAPEADHPEBV?$GenericVector@VSTRING@@@@3_N@Z) referenced in function "public: int __cdecl tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init(char const *,char const *,enum tesseract::OcrEngineMode)" (?Init@TessBaseAPI@tesseract@@QEAAHPEBD0W4OcrEngineMode@2@@Z)
1>redEyeRemover.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl tesseract::TessBaseAPI::SetPageSegMode(enum tesseract::PageSegMode)" (?SetPageSegMode@TessBaseAPI@tesseract@@QEAAXW4PageSegMode@2@@Z) referenced in function main
1>redEyeRemover.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __cdecl tesseract::TessBaseAPI::ProcessPages(char const *,char const *,int,class STRING *)" (?ProcessPages@TessBaseAPI@tesseract@@QEAA_NPEBD0HPEAVSTRING@@@Z) referenced in function main
1>redEyeRemover.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol pixRead referenced in function main
1>C:\Program Files\tesseract\lib\libtesseract302.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
1>C:\Program Files\tesseract\lib\libtesseract302d.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
1>C:\Program Files\tesseract\lib\liblept168.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
1>C:\Program Files\tesseract\lib\liblept168d.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
1>C:\Users\M\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\RedEyeRemover\x64\Debug\RedEyeRemover.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "RedEyeRemover.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I know that these errors are due to debug mode x64 while libraries I'm using are for x86, but How to make them work for x64?

Comment: You could *at least* show us the error messages.. But, this is a Q/A site for *specific* programming problems. *Not* a place to ask for tutorials about basic "get my library to work" problems.

Comment: I'm going to do so, but I don't want to be limited to using Tesseract 3.02 since it's an old version..

Comment: @JesperJuhl errors added in edit :)

Comment: The errors are crystal clear... you are using 32 bit lib files with a 64 bit project. Either configure your project as 32 bits, or add the 64 bit lib files to it.

Comment: I want to find 64 bit lib files, from where can I have them?

Comment: "LNK2019: unresolved external symbol" - that right there indicates that you are not linking with the correct library that provides the symbol. Check your linker options.

Comment: what options? libtesseract302.lib
libtesseract302d.lib
liblept168.lib
liblept168d.lib

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear.. I meant that I failed to do it using source code zip file and didn't found how (I read issues, wiki,etc) and tried..if you know how please tell me.